# Write a program to find sum of squares of all numbers given the following conditions?

Tags: java

> Given two numbers n1 and n2 such that n2>n1, find sum of squares of all numbers from n1 to n2 (including n1 and n2).

My Approach:

I tried to solve the problem using a for loop iterated from `n1` to `n2` but I am getting wrong answer

Below is my function for the code:

```
public int computeSumofSquares (int n1, int n2) 
{
    int sum=0;
    if(n2>n1)
    {
        for(int i=n1;i<=n2;i++)
        {
            sum=((sum)+(n1*n1));
        }
    }
    return sum;
    //write your code here

}
```

For the Input

```
Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output
'8' '10'    192             245
```

Comment: Hint: in your loop, you are not using `i`.

Comment: See. Now this is the proper way to ask a homework question. Clear and concise issue, expected output, actual output, and the attempted code. OP, thank you for making my day. +1

Comment: Also, sum of squares from 1 to n (included) is ``n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6``. Just saying.

Comment: ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: @Abstraction That assumes n1 is 1. For this problem, it would have to be `n2*(n2+1)*(2(n2)+1)/6 - (n1 - 1)*((n1 - 1)+1)*(2(n1 - 1)+1)/6`

Comment: You probably have been playing with programs similar but in this you only need the total so you calculate it in another variable and just add it to sum?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are squaring `n1` on every iteration. Instead you should square `i`. As a short form of `sum=((sum)+(i*i));` you can write `sum += i * i;`

Comment: it's much more readable than `sum=((sum)+(i*i))`, and those parentheses are not needed

Answer (score 8):

Change `sum=((sum)+(n1*n1));` to `sum=((sum)+(i*i));` as `i` is the value incrementing.

Answer (score 5):

In your loop *i* changes every time but in your statement `sum=((sum)+(n1*n1));` nothing changes and each time in your example you are summing 8^2 and the result would be 8*8 + 8*8 + 8*8 = 192.

As everybody said if you change *n1* to *i* in that statement, something like `sum=sum+i*i`, then you will get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for also showing the intermediate forms of the equation. Step debugging through the code would also have shown this to be happening.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already stated, you were always using the lower bound of your interval `n1` to calculate `sum` (instead of your loop variable `i`).

For completeness, I'm posting a java8 solution:

```
int n1 = 8;
int n2 = 10;
int sumOfSquares = IntStream.rangeClosed(n1, n2).map(i -> i * i).sum();

System.out.println(sumOfSquares); // 245
```

Please check [`IntStream` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for further reference.